# Iterate HTML table to highlight differences where cells have multiple comparison items

Tags: javascript, html

I want to highlight differences between the first row of a table and all the other rows column-wise.

I have figured out how to accomplish this when each cell in the table only has 1 item/comparison. But I would like to extend this to multiple comparisons per cell separated by ","s.

Here is the code for the single item per cell. https://jsfiddle.net/t19Lqbkn/
using the following code:

```
 var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
     var matc = table.rows[1]
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        if (col.innerHTML !== matc.cells[j].innerHTML){col.innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>" + col.innerHTML + "</span>";}


   }  
}
```

And here is a table with multiple items per cell. 
https://jsfiddle.net/6c7s9mky/

As you can see in the second link. The first column of the second row, only the item "Eve" should be red, and in the last row of the first column there should be no red color text.

Comment: Here is the accepted answer implemented in the use case. https://jsfiddle.net/6c7s9mky/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String and Array have lots of cool methods

Here an example:

```
const base = "with,hello,string"
let comparison = "string,with,comma";
comparison = comparison.split(",").map(str => 
        base.indexOf(str) !== -1?`<span style="color:red;">${str}</span>`:str
    ).join(",");
```

You can also find a way with RegExp.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Can you please explain the code inside the map() method? I am not familiar with "=>" symbol. And is ${str} a Jquery code? Please an explanation of that code would be very helpful.

Comment: Here the official doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
This method just return a new array of each element function, here the function return a new string or the old string, => function is just a short way to make anonymous function, `${}` to avoid "start"+variable+"end"